# Meditation - hot and expectant in the morning

Tags: personal-practice, daily-life, samatha

I have been doing regular shamata meditation for three months now. By regular I mean at least two sessions of 24 minutes every day and sessions in between, f.ex ten minute sessions at work whenever it's quiet.

Two questions

1 When I sit, after about 3 or 4 for minutes, I get real warm. It's not really that bothering but interestingly this seems to happen in many sessions. After about 12-15 minutes the heat cools off again. Does anyone recognise this?

2 I am a "lucky" man and try to respect my fortunate karma. Not only do I have a stable familiy life, after many years of drugs and drink. I also have a job that I really like. I look forward to work every single day of the year. And my family supports meditation practice and Buddhism.

But my contentment with work actually makes meditation more difficult in the morning, because I'm so expectant. I am getting better at not "looking forward to work", but it's so much easier for me to keep focus in afternoon/evening. Any tips?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Be expectant in life as a house holder but not when meditating. When meditating focus on the task at hand.

With regards to ideal time for meditation, it depends, from person to person and time to time. For some people morning sessions may work well while evenings may not, but for the same people evenings may work well in some periods. Hence it is best to practice at least 2 times a day.

The heating up and cooling experience you mentioned is normal. People experience certain persisting parters of experience like burning sensation, acute pains, vibrations, etc., but these also will change after some time. Do not dwell of give too much importance to the experience but use it to eradicate your past store of Sankara as in the Pahana Suttas ([Pahāna Sutta](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/31.1-Pahana-S-s36.3-piya.pdf), [Avijja Pahana Sutta 2](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/16.9-Avijja-Pahana-S-2-s35.80-piya.pdf)). Be equanimous to the experience knowing it is impermanent (arising and passing).